# How can i generate pdf using xsl-fo footer and header?

Tags: xml, xslt, pdf, footer, xsl-fo

I'm trying to generate pdf but i don't know how can i adding header and footer into each page. I'm using xsl-fo namespace and here is root of xsl code.

```
  <xsl:template match="ROOT">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
              <fo:layout-master-set>
                    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simpleA4"
                          page-height="450mm" page-width="350mm" margin-top="20mm"
                          margin-bottom="20mm" margin-left="20mm" margin-right="20mm">
                          <fo:region-body border="solid thick black" />
                    </fo:simple-page-master>
                    <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="SequenceMaster1">
                          <fo:repeatable-page-master-reference
                                maximum-repeats="3" master-reference="simpleA4" />
                    </fo:page-sequence-master>
              </fo:layout-master-set>
              <xsl:apply-templates />
        </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>
```

and my page template:

```
  <xsl:template match="PAGE">
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="SequenceMaster1"
              text-align="center">
              <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:block font-family="Arial" text-align="left"
                          language="tr">
                          <!-- ======================================Common Bigger table========================================================================================= -->
                          <fo:table width="100%" border-before-width="thin"
                                border-top-width="thick">
                                <fo:table-column column-width="310mm" />
                                <fo:table-body break-after="page" border-width="1mm" border-style="solid" height="410mm">
                                      <fo:table-row>
                                            <fo:table-cell padding-left="2mm" height="410mm">
                                                  <xsl:apply-templates />
                                            </fo:table-cell>
                                      </fo:table-row>
                                </fo:table-body>
                          </fo:table>
                    </fo:block>
              </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm doing it like that - in 'fo:layout-master-set' my page-master looks like that:

```
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="section1-first-page" page-width="8.268055555555555in" page-height="11.693055555555556in" margin-top="35.45pt" margin-bottom="35.45pt" margin-right="70.9pt" margin-left="70.9pt">
         <fo:region-body margin-top="21.25pt" margin-bottom="21.25pt"></fo:region-body>
         <fo:region-before region-name="first-page-header" extent="11in"></fo:region-before>
         <fo:region-after region-name="first-page-footer" extent="11in" display-align="after"></fo:region-after>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
```

fo:region-before defines header region name, while fo:region-after footer region name.

To add content you have to add to 'fo:page-sequence', before 'fo:flow':

```
      <fo:static-content flow-name="first-page-header">
         <fo:block><fo:inline>HEADER TEXT</fo:inline></fo:block>
      </fo:static-content>
      <fo:static-content flow-name="first-page-footer">
         <fo:block><fo:inline>FOOTER TEXT</fo:inline></fo:block>
      </fo:static-content>
```

You can obviously change flow-names to whatever you want. It's just an example from my code.